# Is there a word used to describe situations in which a child is treated like an adult and vice-versa?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Are there specific words to describe the situation in which adults are treated as children and also when children are treated as adults?

Comment: There's https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/infantilize but I'm having trouble finding the reverse